# Filling an array with objects

Tags: java

I need some help with a homework question I am working on.
I need to create a "Library" class that contains an array of Song objects.(capacity of 10).
Then make a method addSong.
Here's what I have so far:

```
public class Library{

    Song[] arr = new Song[10];

    public void addSong(Song s){
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            arr[i] = s;
    }
}
```

My question is: Is there another way to fill the array? i will later need to search for a song based on a index value. So i will create a method like:
public Song getSong(int idx)
Thank you in anticipation for your answers!

Comment: Does your instructor allow you to use ArrayLists?

Comment: You're not "adding" songs there, you're replacing all contents of array (I mean, making all 10 elements the same song). Try to use ArrayList, it's better than doing it "hand-made".

Comment: -1 lack of effort, lack of clarity.

Comment: Everytime  you pass a new song to addSong, you are iterating through the length of the array and replacing all the elements with the song you just passed to addSong

Comment: @ay89 I don't see lack of effort or lack of clarity.

Comment: I can't use ArrayLists. And thank you for pointing it ou. now i see it... I'm filling the array with the same object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really have to use an array (and not an ArrayList or LinkedList), this solution may be the right for you:

```
public class Library{

    private Song[] arr = new Song[10];
    private int songNumber = 0; //the number of Songs already stored in your array

    public void addSong(Song s){
        arr[songNumber++] = s;
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid a runtime-exeption if you add more then 10 songs:

```
public void addSong(Song s){
    if(songNumber<10)
    {
       arr[songNumber++] = s;
    }else{
       //what to do if more then 10 songs are added
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to ++songNumber and check if it is <10

Comment: I think same   `songNumber++` goes for alternate method option.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways of accomplish this.

The logic you're using is more or less ok.

But what you are doing here:

```
public void addSong(Song s){
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        arr[i] = s;
}
```

Is filling all the Songs array with the same song, perhaps this would be better:

```
public void addSong(Song s, int index){
        arr[index] = s;
}
```

Of course, if you pass a negative index, or an index greater than 9, you are gonna be in trouble.

Comment: Since this is a library, you would not want to require the user to specify the location to add the song.

Comment: @Vacation9 is right, I think we should maintain a private integer index to keep track of the next array location

Comment: @Vacation9 I see where you are going, yes he shouldn't, and Chaos advice is good.

Comment: I think OP has to use array, so ArrayList may not be allowed (also since there is no way to set its max capacity). Maybe instead of making user to specify index `Library` should contain some kind of counter of added elements and use it while adding, also if counter is larger then size of array throw some Exception.

Comment: @Pshemo, yes, but since this is **homework** I think with the comments on this answer, and the one by cdMinix OP can do it on his own.

Comment: Thank you for your help! For the index, i can make an if else statement to accomodate the error, such as: if(index<0) index=0        else if index>9 index=9

Comment: Aaand of course I can't vote up because I don't have 15 rep :-(

Comment: Yes, but also follow the suggestion of having a counter that increments every time you add a song, you could also check that the song you are inserting into the array is not a duplicate song.

Comment: @DaniFC You can always select this (or other answer) clicking on the tick at the left side of the answer you want to select.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of an array. This way you can use the `ArrayList.add()` function to append to the end of your array and the `ArrayList.get(int index)` function to get the array entry at index `index`.

```
public class Library{

    ArrayList<Song> arr = new ArrayList<Song>();

    public void addSong(Song s){
        arr.add(s);
    }

    public Song getSong(int index){
        return arr.get(index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Vacation9s' answer:

```
ArrayList<Song> songArray = new ArrayList<Song>();

public void addSong(Song s){
    songArray.add(s);
}
```

Comment: Can't use arrayList. Sorry, should've mentioned in the OP